# Integration of double integral

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

Integration of double integral of.

\begin{equation}
\int_{-\frac{1}{4}}^{0}{\int_{\frac{1}{2}-\sqrt{x+\frac{1}{4}}}^{\frac{1}{2}+\sqrt{x+\frac{1}{4}}}} {e^{y^2}dy  dx} + \int_{0}^{2}{\int_{-1+\sqrt{x+1}}^{1/2+\sqrt{x+\frac{1}{4}}}} {e^{y^2}dy  dx} + \int_{2}^{8}{\int_{-1+\sqrt{x+1}}^{2}} {e^{y^2}dy  dx} 
\end{equation}

Comment: Try $u$-substitution on $y^2$. Then, integration with respect to $x$ is simple enough.

Comment: All those square roots in the limits make me wonder if switching the order of integration would be expedient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we reverse the order of integration the integrands can be transformed into $ye^{y^2}\,dy$ and $y^2e^{y^2}\,dy$.

Here is the region of integration from [desmos.com/calculator](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/iudgcll3cx)

First divide the region into five sections having unique left and right bounding functions of $y$

[image: bounds on integration]

Giving the following region and subregions

[image: Regions of integration]

Then change the order of integration over the five sub-regions to obtain

\begin{eqnarray}
& &\int_0^1\int_{y^2-y}^{0}e^{y^2}dxdy\\&+&\int_{0}^{\sqrt{3}-1}\int_{0}^{y^2+2y}e^{y^2}dxdy\\
&+&2(2-\sqrt{3})\\
&+&\int_{1}^{2}\int_{y^2-y}^2e^{y^2}dxdy\\
&+&\int_{\sqrt{3}-1}^{2}\int_2^{y^2+2y}e^{y^2}dxdy
\end{eqnarray}

You should double check the limits but I believe this is correct.

Comment: After looking this over I found and corrected a few typos and errors.

Comment: +1 for the picture, but looking at it shows that the integral can be expressed as $$\int_0^2 \int_{y^2-y}^{2 y+y^2} e^{y^2} \, dx \, dy = \frac{3}{2} \left(e^4-1\right).$$

Comment: @MarkMcClure Absolutely correct.